# Magento 2.1.1 get custom field added in system.xml file

Tags: magento2, configuration, admin-panel, system.xml, magento-2.1.1

In etc/adminhtml/system.xml I add an additioal field which is

```
<field id="gateway_ID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Gateway ID</label>
</field>
```

But then I can't call this field in my

```
js/view/payment/method-renderer/gateway_renderer.js
```

How can i call this field sa  that i can send it to the third party url in.

```
afterPlaceOrder: function () {}
```

and also i need to get payment information like subtotal of the current checkout.

Comment: You had a `configProviders` for your custom payment? Please, post this part?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this

We have to inject `\Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ConfigFactory` in `ConfigProvider` class

```
const CODE = 'code_gateway';
private $config;
function __construct(
   \Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ConfigFactory $configFactory
) {
   $this->config = $configFactory->create(self::CODE);
}

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    .....
                    'gateway_ID' => $this->config->getValue('gateway_ID')
                    .....
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Now in `gateway_renderer.js`

```
gatewayID: function () {
   return console.log(window.checkoutConfig.payment.code_gateway.gateway_ID);
}
```

on template.html

```
<button class="action primary checkout"
     type="submit"
     data-bind="
     click: gatewayID,
     attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}
                        ">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```